# DataflowTemplates debezium connector issue

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow, debezium

I am referring [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/v2/cdc-parent/README.md) document to perform mysql(installed on local machine) to pubsub data streaming using debezium connector.

My properties file looks like below

```
databaseName=testdb 
databaseUsername=root 
databaseAddress=localhost 
databasePort=3306 
gcpProject=GCP_project_name 
databasePassword=password 
whitelistedTables=instance-name.testdb.testtab 
singleTopicMode=true 
gcpPubsubTopicPrefix=debeziumTest 
databaseManagementSystem=mysql
```

I have already created topic in pubsub with name "debeziumTest".

But the issue is, when i run
`sudo mvn exec:java -pl cdc-embedded-connector -Dexec.args="/path/to/properties-file"`

, it runs without any error:
[image]

but there is no data uploaded to pubsub.

Comment: how did you find out that your instance name is called "instance-name"

Comment: It's hostname of my instance.

Comment: Not sure if you are still working on this issue, but while it is running, have you tried making changes to your MySQL Database, like perform some DML  insert/update/deletes? Would be interested in your response. I am running into the same issue.

Comment: I'd suggest to add/configure a log4j.properties file to src/main/resources to get some log output. Probably you'll find some hints there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, table updates are pushed to a topic that matches this format- ${PREFIX}${DB_INSTANCE}.${DATABASE}.${TABLE}

In your case I believe you should create a topic with the name - "debeziumTestinstance-name.testdb.testtab"

This may not be the only problem based on the warnings I see in the logs you shared.

Comment: I am using single-topic mode. So as per document, we have to mention full topic name in "gcpPubsubTopicPrefix" parameter. The topic name format you mentioned is for multi topic mode

Comment: My bad, did not see the single-topic mode option. I have used debezium with Kafka Connect and faced problems with topics names. So I thought that might be the case here as well.

Comment: Dhruv, Did you make sure binlog is enabled on the MySQL database and changes made (e.g. running an update or insert query on MySQL database table) are captured in binlog for Debezium to pickup the changes?

Comment: yes.. all events are being saved in mysql-bin files.

Comment: land on to this same problem. Guys any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your whitelistedTables.

According to the docuumentation, you should use `${instance}.${database}.${table}`, for your given example it should be `whitelistedTables=testdb.databaseName.testTab` (if testTab is your tablename)